# Spring security Oauth2 Redirect URI setting is ignored when using application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, application.properties, redirect-uri

I am configuring multiple authentication clients for a spring-boot application, and am attempting to override the default redirect URI using:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.redirectUri={baseUrl}/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}
```

and then setting the following in SecurityConfig:

```
http.oauth2Login()
.authorizationEndpoint().baseUri("/oauth2/authorize")
.and()
.redirectionEndpoint().baseUri("/oauth2/callback/*")
```

However, this is not working - when accessing {baseUrl}/oauth2/authorize/google, the client is redirected to

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth/oauthchooseaccount
    ?response_type=code
      &client_id<clientId>
      &scope=email%20profile
      &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flogin%2Foauth2%2Fcode%2Fgoogle
      &flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow
```

with redirect uri parameter "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/google" which is the default set by spring security when redirectUri is not set. If I switch to using application.yml with the below configuration:

```
spring:
    security:
      oauth2:
        client:
          registration:
            google:    
              redirectUri: "{baseUrl}/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}"
```

it works fine. However, for various reasons I want to stick with the application.properties format. Any idea why the setting is ignored?

Comment: It seems your application.properties file is not being picked up. Try setting something simple, like `server.port=9000` in the application.properties and see if the application starts on a difference port. That way we can narrow down the issue.

Comment: Sorry should have made this clear - all other properties in application.properties are being correctly read and the application starts without issue. It is only `spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.redirectUri` which is ignored, unless I use the yml equivalent

Comment: I tried setting the property in one of my applications and it worked as expected, which makes me think there is something different about this application. You could try updating to the latest patch release, for example if you're on Spring Boot 2.6, the latest release is 2.6.5. If you're able to create a minimal sample that reproduces the issue you could open an issue with the Spring Boot team on GitHub.

Comment: Hmm, I'm on  an ancient 2.0.0.RELEASE version, so you may be right - the property may not exist/be respected. I will attempt an upgrade to 2.6.5, but it looks like it may be painful

Comment: I suggest updating to 2.5.x at minimum, since 2.0.x is [no longer supported](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support).

Comment: Just completed the 2.6.5 upgrade - and now it's all working fine, thanks!